# Mongo - How to leftpad values to a certain length?

Tags: mongodb

We have a problem wherein certain strings appear as 123, 00123, 000123.  We need to group by this field and we would like all the above to be considered as one group. I know the length of these values cannot be greater than 6.

The approach I was thinking was to left pad all of these fields in projection with 0s to a length of 6.    One way would be to concat 6 0s first and then do a substr - but there is no length available for me to calculate the indexes for the substr method. -[JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14670)

Is there something more direct?  Couldn't find anything here : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions or has anyone solved this some way?

Comment: What about using mapReduce? Can you  show sample document with the expected result?

Comment: Didn't want to go till mapreduce - it takes longer to run.  However, had to end up doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert then to int. E.g.:

For collection:

```
db.leftpad.insert([
    {key:"123"},
    {key:"0123"},
    {key:"234"},
    {key:"000123"}
])
```

counting:

```
db.leftpad.mapReduce(function(){
    emit(this.key * 1, 1);
}, function(key, count) {
    return Array.sum(count);
}, {out: { inline: 1 }}
).results
```

returns an array:

```
[
    {_id : 123, value : 3},
    {_id : 234, value : 1}
]
```

If you can, it may worth to reduce it once:

```
db.leftpad.find({key:{$exists:true}, intKey:{$exists:false}}).forEach(function(d){
    db.leftpad.update({_id:d._id}, {$set:{intKey: d.key * 1}});
})
```

And then group by `intKey`.

Comment: Thanks! Used mapReduce to converttonumber.